# Windows Phone 8.1 Page Navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm still new with the Windows Phone development. So now I'm going to develop the Windwos Phone 8.1. I really no idea what's the problem with the page navigation. I wrote the code like this

```
private void hbGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
}
```

but it shows me the error (**This page does not contain a definition for "Frame" and no extension method "Frame" accepting the first arguments**)
even i put like the code of bottom also the same...

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

Comment: Well, not sure it will help but the error usually means that "Frame" isn't part of your Page instance.

Comment: @ShalinVed Yup...the error is means like this..so what should I do to prevent the error occur?

Comment: Can you try.. 
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Navigation depends on the kind of your project:

If it is **Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight** then you should use [NavigationService.Navigate() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> Applies to: Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 | Windows Phone OS 7.1

If you are targeting **Windows Phone RunTime** then you should use [Frame.Navigate method()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate.aspx):

> Minimum supported phone Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Runtime apps only]

Comment: yess...thanks for the info, have no problem now with the page redirect =)

Comment: May I know what is the differences between Windows Phone 8.1 runtime apps and silverlight??

Comment: There are different kind of models. [Windows Runtime apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx) can be Universal apps (not only for phone), you also will find some methods that are applied only to WinRT. The [8.1 Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642082(v=vs.105).aspx) follows WP8.0 and you can add new features to old code without significant modification in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Frame isn't a part of a Page.
I do navigation the following way

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

you just have to pass the name of the xaml page you want to navigate to.

Answer (score 2):

I use this little Navigation Service class I created to allow me to navigate different pages from within the ViewModel of my Windows Phone 8.1 app. FYI, INavigate is part of Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.

```
public class NavigationService : INavigate
{
    private Frame Frame { get { return (Frame)Window.Current.Content; } }

    public bool Navigate(Type sourcePageType)
    {
       return Frame.Navigate(sourcePageType);
    }
    public void Navigate(Type sourcePageType, object parameter)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(sourcePageType, parameter);
    }

    public void ClearStack()
    {
        ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStack.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Virtual method used by the <see cref="GoBackCommand"/> property
    /// to invoke the <see cref="Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.GoBack"/> method.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void GoBack()
    {
        if (this.Frame != null && this.Frame.CanGoBack) this.Frame.GoBack();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Virtual method used by the <see cref="GoBackCommand"/> property
    /// to determine if the <see cref="Frame"/> can go back.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the <see cref="Frame"/> has at least one entry 
    /// in the back navigation history.
    /// </returns>
    public virtual bool CanGoBack()
    {
        return this.Frame != null && this.Frame.CanGoBack;
    }
}
```