# New Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 apps

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have just updated my Windows Phone HTC 8S to Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview and I would like to begin playing around with any new API's. I did come across the Windows.Phone.System.LockScreenExtensibility namespace, but it says:

> Minimum supported phone  Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Phone Silverlight
>   8.1 apps only]

Is there a difference between normal Windows Phone 8 apps that we're currently making, and "Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1" apps? I've never heard of Silverlight 8.1 apps before.

Comment: For other developers who are starting to develop on the 8.1 platform, and are wondering what's the difference: check this video out, it really helped me understand what is going on. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-550

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 is a '*continuation*' of Windows Phone 8 Apps (apart from native apps and some exceptions, most of WP8.0 apps were Silverlight 8.0). It gives more possibilites with little change to your code, you can read more [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642082(v=vs.105).aspx):

> The Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app model gives Windows Phone 8 developers access to some of the newest features available in Windows Phone Store apps without significantly modifying existing Windows Phone 8 code.

When developing Windows Store apps under 8.1 there are two main paths: Windwos RunTime Apps and mentioned Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 -> [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn632732.aspx). Both have advantages and disadvantages. Windows Runtime Apps can be far more easily ported to other devices, you will also find some API's available only for runtime apps and some other Controls under WinRT. You may also want to read about [Universal Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx).

As for Silverligt you may also look [at this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/23).

More about programming concepts you will find [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750304.aspx).

So when you find such a sentence:

> Applies to: Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 | Windows Phone OS 7.1

it means that it can't be used with WP8.1 RunTime Apps. And vice-versa:

> Minimum supported phone Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Runtime apps only]

only for RunTime apps. Good example here is [different navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23260923/2681948) in those two models.

Comment: Thank you very much @Romasz. I was quite confused when I read it on the MSDN page because something I read a while ago lead me to think that MS was getting rid of Silverlight.

Comment: @spike.y Note that 8.1 has backward compatibility - WP8.0 apps should run without issue. It's a question to Microsoft what it will do with Silverlight/WinRT in the future - note that there are thousands of Apps running under Silverlight. If I was starting a new App, then I would choose WinRT - it's easier to port it to other devices (in many cases it's already an Universal App), there are quite nice things like BackgroundTasks and so on. If you were coding under WP8.0, then it's not so hard to write under WinRT. There are some new things to learn, but many stay the same.