# Windows Phone 8.1 - DLL reference problems when using the camera

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a simple camera application according to [the MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx).

All I did was installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and then created a new Visual C# \ Store-Apps \ Windows Phone-Apps \ Empty App Template and added the code to my MainPage.xaml.cs.

The first problem is, that it does not find the namespaces `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media`, `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` and `Microsoft.Devices`. According to the tutorial, I have to add the Xna DLL in the "Add references" .net Tab, but unfortunately, there is no .net tab. I only have the following categories:

-Assembly (All Assemblys are already references)
-Project
-Windows Phone 8.1 (only 5 DLLs, but different ones)

After a lot of searching, I found them in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\AppDeploy\MdilXapCompilev8.0\Framework', but there is no System.IO.IsolatedStorage DLL.

When I ommit this using directive, I end up getting an error because it does not know `this.Dispatcher`.

Am I missing something? Do I have to install anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that [the link you have provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx) concerns *WP8.1 Silverlight* and you might have chosen WP8.1 Runtime project. Those are [different API's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23460644/2681948) - XNA is not supported in RunTime, you also won't find *Microsoft.Devices* there.

If you want to create your Camera App for WP8.1 Silverlight encure that you have chosen *(Windows Phone Silverlight)* template. Otherwise, of course you can also write Camera App but with different API - you may take [a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23606620/2681948),also you may find something useful [here at blog](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-take-a-photo-in-windows-runtime/).