# What are the differences between the types of Windows phone 8.1 applications?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to understand the 2 main differences in Windows Phone 8/8.1 development.

If I start a new Project I can see (just the main ones I am concerned about),

1. Blank App (Windows Phone)
2. Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight).

When I add both (to compare with) I can see the markup is the same.

what are the differences that I need to be aware of and should I choose one over the other?

Comment: It's very broad topic, those are different types of apps, different API's (though they share some things) and so on. You can find some information in [this answer (check also links mentioned there)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23460644/2681948).

Comment: @Romasz Hi, you seem to be the man on Windows Phone! I am glad you give so much time on these forums.  I find your link useful.  Knowing how Microsoft like to drop stuff without any consideration to others I will take a hunch and not use Silverlight. Thanks

Comment: I don't think that Microsoft will drop Silverlight just like that - there are thousands of awesome apps using it - they just can't. Thought Windows Store apps (RunTime) are easier to make Universal, becouse of that I would focus on it. Everything of course depends on your needs and time.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this