# Difference between Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 development

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on Windows Phone development. For that I installed required SDK. I do create new project with Windows Phone 8.1, but gradually found that it don't support WCF service as we can not add service reference in assembly. After research I found that Windows Phone 8.1 doesn't support WCF services([refernce](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9ab43a4c-499a-4f2e-81e5-c1ab5acbe9bf/wcf-add-service-reference-not-supported-for-windows-phone-81-xaml-applications?forum=wpdevelop)). Then I add new Silverlight Windows Phone 8.1 project and found that it support web service([Work Around](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/myamama/archive/2014/06/24/workaround-to-adding-service-reference-to-windows-phone-8-1-runtime-app.aspx)). While development in Silverlight project I found that their is another difference between two type of project in syntax also, e.g. Navigation to another page,

Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight support following syntax:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(@"/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

where as Windows Phone 8.1 support([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259534/windows-phone-8-1-page-navigation))

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

Now I am getting confuse with those type of project and unable to find those differences. Please help me out.

Comment: [Here you have a MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn632732.aspx) to both API's. Also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23460644/2681948) may help little.

Comment: Here are some differences: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/15/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-choose-your-windows-phone-xaml-app-model.aspx

Answer (score 1):

- Silverlight navigates between pages using Uri that point to xaml
  files.
- Windows Phone Runtime (8.1 Store Apps) uses navigation with
  pagetypes.

If your app is a Windows Phone Silverlight (8 or 8.1) App, you have to use the first approach for navigating between pages. 
The other one simply isn't available to your project.

Windows Phone currently has multiple different application models available, which differ significantly. I know that can be quite confusing When looking for samples and guidance make sure the article you found is matching your app type (i.e. Silverlight).